# efficient database design inheritance

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to design a database with have 2 categories.
There are 2 subcategories in each category, but they are very similar to other category like:

## preventive equipment maintenance:

- cat1

  - id, equipment,model, series, accesories,date, cost, status
- cat 2

  - id, equipment,model, series, accesories,date, cost, status

## corrective equipment maintenance

- cat1

  - id, new equipment, old equipment, borreowed equipment, description
- cat 2

  - id, new equipment,model, series, accesories,date, cost, old equipment, borreowed equipment, description

So as you can see the only diference between data collected on  **preventive equipment maintenance** is the cat (either cat1 or  cat2).
To solve this I thought to make a table like

```
CREATE TABLE `preventive_e`(
      id          INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      equipment   VARCHAR(25) ,
      cat         VARCHAR(4) ,      
      CONSTRAINT `uc_Info_E` UNIQUE (`id`)           
);
INSERT INTO `preventive_e` values (1,'nintendo','cat1');
INSERT INTO `preventive_e` values (2,'psp','cat2');
```

Now in corrective it would be the same, however they are not the same fields, they are almost the same fields, if is cat1 i want to store only some fields, but if is cat 2 i want to store same fields but some more fields

Is there a way to use inheritance or something?, extending the fields but being able to add more particular fields? How would a query look like.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbec84)

Comment: why declare a field that only contains 4 char strings as varchar(50)? char(4) seems more appropriate.

Comment: i posted an answer but reading the question again and we need more description about what is related to what.  equipment has exactly 2 categories?   equipment has maintenance? preventative, corrective , both or neither?   an  category is described by id, new equipment, old equipment, borreowed equipment, description?  or is that a list of example categories?

Comment: You're actually trying to normalize your tables, which is a good thing, but it's hard to follow what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not call the table something generic to both like `equipment_maint` and have a column acting as a flag for it's usage.

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4194d/1)

```
CREATE TABLE `equipment_maint`(
  id          INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  equipment   VARCHAR(25)  ,
  cat         VARCHAR(50) ,  
  type       varchar(20),  /* usage on type of maintenance */
  CONSTRAINT `uc_Info_E` UNIQUE (`id`)           
);
```